# Simplifying Organization Name Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This topic is about simplifying a regex.

I have been "Client Side" validating a form I created using Javascript. This form requires a business to signup using it's company name. I have created a regex that seems to work well, but it does have a couple issues. First issue is that the regex only allows companies, who's names are 5 words or less, to be considered valid. I know how I can make it allow more words but that would require more code, which could be considered sloppy work. Is there a way that I can correct the following regex to allow companies to sign up, and not worry about how many words they have in their name? Would XSS be an issue with the way I currently have my regex? Thanks for all and any help.

```
}
if(!Bname.match(/^[0-9A-Za-z'-]*\s{1}[0-9A-Za-z'-]*$|^[0-9A-Za-z'-]*$|^[0-9A-Za-z'-]*
\s{1}[0-9A-Za-z'-]*\s{1}[0-9A-Za-z'-]*$|^[0-9A-Za-z'-]*\s{1}[0-9A-Za-z'-]*\s{1}[0-9A-
Za-z'-]*\s{1}[0-9A-Za-z'-]*$|^[0-9A-Za-z'-]*\s{1}[0-9A-Za-z'-]*\s{1}[0-9A-Za-z'-]*
\s{1}[0-9A-Za-z'-]*\s{1}[0-9A-Za-z'-]*$/))
{
```

Comment: What are your requirements other than only allowing the characters "0-9A-Z-a-z'-" in any "word"? I'm not going to guess all the requirements by trying to decipher that RegEx.

Comment: Are you sure a regex is a reasonable way to check for company names, which may consist of arbitrary characters, and an arbitrary number of words?

Comment: @tenub  "0-9A-Za-z'-" are my only requirements.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am just wanting to grab a companies name. While at the same time preventing any XSS. I know that PHP will need to be done to prevent XSS before submitting data to the database but is it pointless to try and stop XSS through Javascript. Since javascript can be turned off? I just want to be secure in all I do and do not want someone to drop my tables. I guess if I have good PHP validation set up then it wouldnt matter if XSS is passed through Client side validation.

Comment: It's best to just let the user enter any input and use pdo and proper sql injection prevention methods before inserting the company name into your database.

Comment: @tenub I will follow this advice. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your regex like this:

```
Bname.match(/^[0-9A-Za-z'-]+(?:\s[0-9A-Za-z'-]+)*$/)
```

However, it will not match names with accented characters and other symbols that may exist in a company name (like Yahoo!)

Comment: Thanks for this info. I put it in and it worked exactly how I wanted it to. Quick question. If I wanted to allow the exclamation mark would I do the following?

Comment: Bname.match(/^[0-9A-Za-z'-/!]+(?:\s[0-9A-Za-z'-/!]+)*$/)

Comment: `Bname.match(/^[0-9A-Za-z'!-]+(?:\s[0-9A-Za-z'!-]+)*$/)` would be correct. Either escape "-" or put it at the beginning or end of the brackets. You also don't need to escape "!".

Comment: @tenub Thanks my friend. I am very appreciative of the information and help.